# unpredicted output binary search tree in python

Tags: python, binary-tree

```
class Node(): 
    def __init__(self,data, left=None, right=None): 
        self.data = data 
        self.left = left
        self.right = right 
class BSTree(): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.root = None
    def add(self,data):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(data)
            self.reset()
        else:
            while self.curNode is not None:
                if data < self.curNode.data:
                    self.curNode = self.curNode.left
                elif data > self.curNode.data:
                    self.curNode = self.curNode.right
            self.curNode=Node(data)
            self.reset()
    def pprint(self,Node,indent): 
        if Node is not None:
            self.pprint(Node.left, indent+1) 
            print indent*"     ",Node.data
            self.pprint(Node.right, indent+1)  
if __name__=="__main__": 
    y = BSTree() 
    for pres in ["OBAMA","BUSHW","CLINTON","BUSHG","REGAN","CARTER","FORD","NIXON","JOHNSON"]:
        y.add(pres) 
    y.pprint(y.root,0)
```

This code runs without error but my output is

```
 OBAMA
```

I cannot figure out why the code above does not have errors at runtime but only add's the first node to the tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. Thank you to danben for guidance in getting there! It was a combination of what he was saying and looking at some other implementations on my own. Here is what I came up with in case anyone was wondering.

```
class Node(): 
    def __init__(self,data, left=None, right=None): 
        self.data = data 
        self.left = left
        self.right = right 
class BSTree(): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.root = None

    def __add(self,node,data):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(data)
        if node is None:
            return Node(data)
        else:
            if data < node.data:
                node.left = self.__add(node.left,data)
            elif data > node.data:
                node.right = self.__add(node.right,data)
            return node

    def add(self,data):
        self.__add(self.root,data)

    def __preorder(self,node): 
        if node is not None:
            print node.data 
            self.__preorder(node.left) 
            self.__preorder(node.right)

    def preorder(self):
        self.__preorder(self.root)

    def __inorder(self,node): 
        if node is not None:
            self.__inorder(node.left)
            self.__inorder(node.right)
            print node.data

    def inorder(self):
        self.__inorder(self.root)

    def __postorder(self,node): 
        if node is not None:
            self.__postorder(node.left)
            print node.data
            self.__postorder(node.right)

    def postorder(self):
        self.__postorder(self.root)

    def pprint(self,Node,indent): 
        if Node is not None:
            self.pprint(Node.right, indent+1) 
            print indent*"     ",Node.data
            self.pprint(Node.left, indent+1) 
    def leafcount(self,Node): 
        if Node is None: 
            return 0 
        if self.atLeaf(Node): 
            return 1 
        else: 
            return self.leafcount(Node.left)+self.leafcount(Node.right) 

if __name__=="__main__": 

    y = BSTree()

    for pres\
        in ["OBAMA","BUSHW","CLINTON","BUSHG","REGAN","CARTER","FORD","NIXON","JOHNSON"]:
        y.add(pres)

    y.pprint(y.root,0)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 def __add(self,node,data): 
        if node is None: 
            return Node(data) 
        else: 
            if data < node.data: 
                node.left = self.__add(node.left,data) 
            elif data > node.data: 
                node.right = self.__add(node.right,data)
```

This function is incorrect.  It always overwrites the first left or right child of the root node, unless the root is `None`.

Since this is homework, I won't write the correct version for you, but here is a hint - first find the spot where the new node should be added, THEN assign to the left or right child.

**Edit**: in response to your update - you are very close now.  Your last error lies in the fact that you are not actually attaching the new node to anything.  Rather, you're assigning it to `curNode` which is not part of the structure of your tree.  You instead want to link it to the parent node as either the right or left child.

Comment: ok i ended up getting rid of the __add method and the recursion. It looks like http://python.pastebin.com/m1de4a7c8

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the error message at the bottom.  That should be self-explanatory - you are checking `curNode.left` before you check whether `curNode` is `None`.

Comment: @danben actually it will be true only when either `left` or `right` are `None` because the `and` will not test `right` if `left` is already a false value. I think it's a confusing expression though

Comment: changed it to while not(curNode.left and curNode.right) is None. and now i get 
      BUSHG
           JOHNSON
 OBAMA
      REGAN

Comment: @gnibbler - that's right, my mistake.  @controlfreak123 - you need to take a step back and think about what the actual logic is that you're trying to implement at this part.  Update your original post with that and then I'll give you a hint on how to implement it.

Comment: well i don't see how its not connecting it to self.root because the very beginning sets self.curNode to self.root and then i set self.curNode to either the left or right child of self.root. I don't see how you can traverse the tree nodes without doing it that way?

Comment: First of all, you aren't setting `self.curNode` to `self.root` anywhere.  Second, you don't do any assignment until `self.curNode` is `None` - at that point you have no way to link the new node to its parent.  You need to have a reference to the parent to be able to set its `left` or `right` property.